# Ant throws error when String is too long

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a string whose value is very long,when i compile with Eclipse it    is getting compiled, but when i build it with Ant , it throws error saying 
"error: constant string too long".

I tried something like this

```
         public static final String CONSTANT  =     
         org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(new String[]
         {
           //String long value
         }
```

But it doesn't work, any help will be appreciative.

Comment: This sounds like the version of Java you are using in your Eclipse is not the same as the one you are using for building.  That being said, could you post the versions of Java you are using?

Comment: Does it need to be a string in the source file, or is it some data that you can represent in some other way?

Comment: I am using java version "1.8.0_40" and same is configured with eclipse and ant

Comment: When using the join approach, did you split your string into <64kB chunks?

Comment: I mean `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join`, as in your question.

Comment: I found the solution , By using this it works for me

Comment: String theString2 = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(rootDir + "/properties/filename.text")), "UTF-8");

Comment: Thanks all, for answer and comments to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has it's own [built-in compiler](http://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html), which is quite separate from the one you'd normally use from Ant or other external applications. That is precisely why you only need the JRE to *run* Eclipse and not a JDK to compile the code you write.

The page linked to above gives one way to use the Eclipse compiler from an Ant buildfile by defining `build.compiler`, which may make your Eclipse and Ant environments more compatible.

Other than that, you may want to think about *why* your strings are so large, there may be a better way.